# How do I do geocoding (NOT reverse geocoding) on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, geocoding

I am perplexed as to why there is an iPhone API for Reverse Geocoding (lat/long to address) but NOT for regular Geocoding (address to lat/long).

I want to be able to display an annotation on a map (MKMapView) at an address entered by the user.  (As text, not by touching the map)  As far as I can tell, that means I have to determine the lat/long for the entered address.

It looks like it can be done using HTTP, but then, Reverse Geocoding ALSO could have been done that way, too.  Why did they support one but not the other?

Answers as to "why?" or "how?" would both be appreciated.

*** Anyone learned anything new on this topic?  Any announcements I haven't heard about?

Comment: iPhone SDK 3.0 is still under NDA. You really need to ask this question on http://devforums.apple.com. Also, I happen to know you'll find the answer there ;-)

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I keep forgetting about the NDA -- I just don't think that way.  Good thing I don't have anyone asking *me* questions...

Comment: In iOS5, use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7936272/242848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and wrote a geocoding class. [http://web.me.com/andreas.bungert/erle_muss_sein/iPhone_Development/Einträge/2009/7/9_Geocoding_im_SDK.html](http://web.me.com/andreas.bungert/erle_muss_sein/iPhone_Development/Eintr%C3%A4ge/2009/7/9_Geocoding_im_SDK.html)

Best Regards

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I ended up using code supplied by Bill Dudney (http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdmapkit/using-the-map-kit).

Comment: @VansFannel I reuploaded it under http://files.mettigel-software.com/TSGeocoder.zip 
There are some bugs in it, i think. If I got some time i will remove them

Answer (score 4):

Merrimack wrote an answer  here with a useful example..

[Forward geocoding from the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140404/forward-geocoding-from-the-iphone/2444249#2444249)

There is a nice blog post of him

http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this question long after it was asked:

As brainjam notes, since iOS 5 Apple's CLGeocoder class supports [forward-geocoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW8).

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the source code available from:

http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdmapkit/using-the-map-kit

In what part the forward geocoding used?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like that example uses either form of geocoding (forward OR reverse)

Comment: That's the link you provided, and that was the only MapKit source could get there. How did you get the source code you used? Or, was it a compiled commercial library?

Comment: I must have provided the wrong link, sorry.  I don't have time to backtrack now, but I will try to figure it out later.

Comment: @Amagrammer: Have you updated the url to get the correct geocoder?