# Forward geocoding from the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, geocoding

Given that the mapkit doesn't provide forward geocoding functionality today, can anyone provide help on how I can i use a search bar to return a latitude and longitude coordinate from a user inputted address today. If someone can provide sample code that would be great.

Answer (score 32):

iOS 5 now allows for forward Geocoding:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW5

I hope this helps!

Comment: With iOS6 this will probably be the only usable solution (besides possibly Yahoo) as I doubt Google will be happy with you overlaying Google geocoding data on an Apple map...

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner I think Google would be fine with this, but Apple?...perhaps not.

Comment: It's Google's TOS that prevents it.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits (no Google geocoding data displayed on non-Google maps).  Apple doesn't care where you get the data for things you overlay on a map.  Now that Apple is not using Google for map data there are no restrictions on how you can use MapKit.

Answer (score 26):

I've created a forward geocoding API for Google's geocoding server. Check out my blogpost:
http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/

Comment: Needs to be updated to the new Google Geocoding API (for instance, no API key is needed now). Besides that, does great job. Thanks @Merrimack. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Thanks DenTheMan, however the API does support both V2 and V3 (latest with no API key). Has been that way since the first release.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *404 Not Found*.

Answer (score 15):

I have created [SVGeocoder](https://github.com/samvermette/SVGeocoder), a simple forward **and** reverse geocoder class for iOS. It uses the Google Geocoding API as well and returns an [MKPlacemark](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

This is how you geocode an address string:

```
NSString *addressString = @"3245 St-Denis, Montreal"
SVGeocoder *geocodeRequest = [[SVGeocoder alloc] initWithAddress:addressString];
[geocodeRequest setDelegate:self];
[geocodeRequest startAsynchronous];
```

And you reverse geocode an CLLocationCoordinate2D object like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.54181, -73.62928);
SVGeocoder *rGeocoderRequest = [[SVGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate];
[rGeocoderRequest setDelegate:self];
[rGeocoderRequest startAsynchronous];
```

The SVGeocoderDelegate offers these 2 methods:

```
- (void)geocoder:(SVGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark;
- (void)geocoder:(SVGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: Important note for users: if you use the Google Geocoding API, you have to display the result on a map.

Comment: great code, but why do you import AddressBook framework in SVGeocoder?

Comment: @luyuan because MKPlacemark requires it for the address components (not the case anymore with CLPlacemark in iOS 5 I think)

Comment: @samvermette Thx for your reply:) Yes Im with IOS 5

Comment: Now totally useless for iOS developers:  From the Google TOS: "Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Comment: It works very well for me... I'm NOT using a Google Map!

Answer (score 3):

I have done some small work on forward and reverse geocoding using CLGeocoder in iOS5 CoreLocation framework on github hope it help you.
https://github.com/Mangesh20/geocoding

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue with the current version of MapKit. File a bugreport and dupe #6628720 so they make fixing it a priority.

In the meantime, there are forward Geocoding APIs from [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html), via [Yahoo Placemaker](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placemaker/), or [Cloudmade](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/geocoding-http-api).

Answer (score 2):

There is also a framework here: https://github.com/tylerhall/CoreGeoLocation

Comment from docs:
*An Objective GeoCoder and Reverse Geocoder wrapping around Yahoo's Geocoding services or Google's Geo APIs primarily.*

Comment: Important note for users: if you use the Google Geocoding API, you have to display the result on a map. Yahoo doesn't seem to have this limitation.

Comment: You have to display the result on a GOOGLE map.  Important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality in MapKit. The best you can do is to call a third party web service. Google has some APIs to do this and so had Yahoo I think. Both have restrictions on commercial use though, so read the agreement.