# How to find latitude longitude from the address?

Tags: iphone

I am using MapKit for google map? How to find latitude longitude using address?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140404/forward-geocoding-from-the-iphone/2444249#2444249 here is an example..

Answer (score 2):

it seems to me that the mapkit framework only expose api for the reverse geocoding (from point to address)

however, you can do it by calling this web services (plain http + json, use the [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON) library for parsing the response or [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)): http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

Comment: Apparently due to licensing agreements between Apple, Google and TomTom. According to quick Google search.