# how to get latitude and longitude from the address in MKMapkit?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one application .In which i want to get latitude and longitude from the address.I dont want to use java script.Is it possble then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, MKMapKit does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

MapKit has no geocoding support (only reverse geocoding) but Google offers a [HTTP Geocoding service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html) that's very easy to use – assuming you comply with their license terms:

> Note: the geocoding service may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

Use the example from Apple’s «Location Awareness Programming guide: Geocoding Location Data» to pinpoint your location on the map, then call Google Geocoding Service (post a request, parse the result json/xml data) to get the address.

Comment: There is also a couple of readymade libraries mentioned here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140404/forward-geocoding-from-the-iphone) available to make the dirty work for you.