# How can I find a city and show it on a MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I'm developing an **iPhone application** to search cities on a MKMapView. The user specify a city and then it show its location on a MKMapView. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forward geocoding from the iPhone ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140404/forward-geocoding-from-the-iphone)

Comment: Perhaps, but as the forward geocoding is not available in iPhone, I'm try to do in other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: iOS 5 now includes [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder), which will do just that for you.

You could use [Google's Geocoder REST API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). A request looks like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=city&sensor=true_or_false
```

Since the response is in JSON format, you'll need a [JSON parser](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I know that service. The problem is a paid service and I looking for something cheaper (is a paid service because I'm going to sell the application). Thanks again.

Comment: Google's Geocoder REST API is a free service. You don't even need an API key. I'm pretty sure you can sell an app that uses Google's Geocoder REST API.

Comment: I've asked to Google, and this is his answer: There is no need to use a key if you are using the FREE service.  If
you use the free service, terms and conditions apply.  These are
mostly aimed at preventing people copying the data, and/or using the
data outside of a Google branded application (e.g.a map), and/or
reselling the free service.   There are also speed and volume limits
to prevent users hogging the service.
If no-one can see the results of geocoding without buying your
application, you are re-selling Google's service and should get a
licence.