# Parase JSON in iphone app with json-framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json-framework

i found this framewok , it seem easy to user , http://stig.github.com/json-framework/. In the exemple , he have this json :

> {
>       "resultats":{
>       "joueurs":[
>       {
>       "nom":"Jean Martin",
>       "score":10000
>       },
>       {
>       "nom":"Pierre Dupond",
>       "score":"9000"
>       },
>       {
>       "nom":"Alice Bateau",
>       "score":"8500"
>       }
>       ]
>       }
>       }

and he parase it like this :

```
NSDictionary *json    = [myJSON JSONValue];

//récupération  des résultats
NSDictionary *resultats    = [json objectForKey:@"resultats"];

//récupération du tableau de Jouers
NSArray *listeJoueur    =  [resultats objectForKey:@"joueurs"];

//On parcourt la liste de joueurs
for (NSDictionary *dic in listeJoueur) {

//création d'un objet Joueur
Joueur *joueur = [[Joueur alloc] init];

//renseignement du nom
joueur.nom = [dic objectForKey:@"nom"];

//renseingement du score
joueur.score = [[dic objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
```

But me ,i don't have array in my JSON . This is my json :

> {"escarrival":"NCE","escdepart":"DJE","estarrival":"08.24","estdepart":"06.27","flynumber":"TU
>   0286","fstatuts":"Vol
>   atterri","proarrival":"08.25","prodepart":"06.30","realarrived":"----","realdepart":"06.27"}

How can i parase it please ? thankx

Comment: I don't know about json-framework, but see this for a solution with JSONKit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059796/how-to-get-locationcoordinates-from-city-name-in-iphone-sdk/6059901#6059901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pars it just extract the objects for the keys.

```
    NSDictionary *jsonDict    = [myJSON JSONValue];

    //création d'un objet Joueur
    Joueur *joueur = [[Joueur alloc] init];

    //renseignement du nom
    joueur.escarrival = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"escarrival"];

    joueur.escdepart = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"escdepart"];

    joueur.estarrival = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"estarrival"];
    joueur.estdepart = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"estdepart"];
    joueur.flynumber = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"flynumber"];
    joueur.fstatuts = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"fstatuts"];
    joueur.flynumber = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"flynumber"];
    joueur.proarrival = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"proarrival"];
    joueur.prodepart = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"prodepart"];
    joueur.realarrived = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"realarrived"];
    joueur.realdepart = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"realdepart"];
```

Edit:

For better understanding of NSDictionary read [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html) from Apple

Comment: Is ok but try to read the edit link for better understanding of Collections. It will help you in the future.