# CLRegion from address

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocationmanager

Is there a way to get a CLRegion from an address ? I want to use startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: to monitor when an address is entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly.  Convert the street address to a latitude/longitude using [forward geocoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1140404/154803) which will give you the CLRegion center point.  Then you need to pick a radius and you can create the region with [initCircularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLRegion/initCircularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier:)