# Using mapkit in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I would like a map inside my iphone app which I want to query with search terms depending on certain values.

Does the mapkit framework accept queries of e.g. The United States and then display them?

I know this is really simple compared to the uses available from mapkit, that is why I wonder if it is covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be useful:

[How do I do geocoding (NOT reverse geocoding) on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988060/how-do-i-do-geocoding-not-reverse-geocoding-on-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Currently MapKit only provides Reverse Geocoding from coordinates to an address. For forward geocoding (an address or placename to coordinates) you'll need to use a geocoding API.

If your application only has a set number of things to be searched and you know the coordinates (like countries in your example) you could store and search them in core data, sqllite etc.