# How to get latitude and longitude of a city?

Tags: iphone, google-maps-api-3, mkmapview, google-geocoder, mkpinannotationview

I am designing a project in which I have used two text fields. One is for source address and another one is for destination address.

Now, I want to get latitude and longitude of both addresses and then draw it on map view.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: it differ from previous question. I want to use for two text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this post for geocoding

http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/03/23/geocoding-on-the-iphone-getting-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-an-address/

[How do I do geocoding (NOT reverse geocoding) on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988060/how-do-i-do-geocoding-not-reverse-geocoding-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Do check out [SVGeocoder](http://samvermette.com/164). It's able to perform both forward and reverse gecoding via Google API. Not to mention it's also very easy to use.