# To get latitude and longitude from user given location

Tags: iphone, google-maps

In my app the user gives the location name for eg: "New York". in the text field, app gives the location ie latitude & longitude of New York.
Which method I should use . please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do geocoding (NOT reverse geocoding) on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988060/how-do-i-do-geocoding-not-reverse-geocoding-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Google Geocoding API below,

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Winnetka&sensor=false

In the place of address=Winnetka you can write address= New York,

You will get the lat and long in the xml responce so just parse the output.

Enjoy!

Comment: if you satisfy with answer then please mark true it.and increase the count ranking

Comment: @Hardik : I guess you will need too much effort to get your answer be accepted.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Places Autocomplete API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete), which you may find useful.